# Dynamics CRM: How to create an email record with attachment using C#

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, email-attachments, dynamics-365

I want to create an email record, and will it mark as 'Received', and may be added attachment to this new email record. Anybody know how to do that using C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [Official example](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerApps-Samples/blob/1adb4891a312555a2c36cfe7b99c0a225a934a0d/cds/orgsvc/C%23/SendEmail/SendEmail/SampleProgram.cs) code but no attachment included, so I will use my code here:

There are three steps:

1. Create an email record.
2. Create attachment records for email.
3. Send this email with `SendEmailRequest`

Here is the sample code:

```
// 1. Create the email record.
Entity newEmail = new Entity("email");
newEmail["subject"] = "your email subject";
newEmail["description"] = "your email content";

Entity toparty = new Entity("activityparty");
toparty["addressused"] = "to@email.com";
Guid contactid = new Guid();
toparty["partyid"] = new EntityReference("contact", contactid);
newEmail["to"] = new Entity[] { toparty };

Entity fromparty = new Entity("activityparty");
fromparty["addressused"] = "from@email.com";
Guid userid = new Guid();
fromparty["partyid"] = new EntityReference("systemuser", userid);
newEmail["from"] = new Entity[] { fromparty };

Guid targetEmailId = serviceproxy.Create(newEmail);

// 2. Create Attachment for email
Entity linkedAttachment = new Entity("activitymimeattachment");
linkedAttachment.Attributes["objectid"] = new EntityReference("email", targetEmailId);
linkedAttachment.Attributes["objecttypecode"] = "email";
linkedAttachment.Attributes["filename"] = "DemoAttachment.pdf";
linkedAttachment.Attributes["mimetype"] = "application/pdf";
linkedAttachment.Attributes["body"] = "your attachment file stream in BASE64 format string";
serviceproxy.Create(linkedAttachment);

// 3. Send the email with SendEmailRequest method.
SendEmailRequest sendEmailRequest = new SendEmailRequest
{
    EmailId = targetEmailId,
    TrackingToken = "",
    IssueSend = true
};
SendEmailResponse sendEmailresp = (SendEmailResponse)serviceproxy.Execute(sendEmailRequest);
```

More ref:

`activityparty` is a special type, you can get more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/activityparty-entity)

`SendEmailRequest` official document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/org-service/samples/send-email)